# HTC One M7 won't update

Tags: updates, stagefright

My HTC One M7 has been notifying me about a new update (v 7.18.111.35, Android Security Patch for *libstageFright*) for the past few months. And every time I try to install it, this is the result:

[image]

All I can do is reboot and the phone operates as normal.

It's not rooted, not modded in any way and I did a data wipe/factory reset about a week ago, but still it won't install.

My carrier is T-Mobile (although I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it)

Does anyone have experience with this?
And maybe have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `Installation Aborted:Status 7` error indicates an assertion fail during execution of the updater-script binary inside OTA file. This can be due to one of 2 things:

1. The OTA zip itself is corrupted (bad download). This then indicates a signature mismatch error.
2. The updater-script could not find the appropriate properties in your system during execution. This means that the updater-script checks for some particular values in your `build.prop`, which allow it to confirm that it is being installed on the system it was meant to be installed on. The updater-script has assertions, a kind of safety mechanism (or exception handlers, if you prefer). to verify this. This indicates an incompatible system software version versus OTA zip.

[image: assertions]

In both cases, you would be better off redownloading and double checking the update(checking the checksums if any are provided), or manually updating via `adb sideload` (Recovery Mode option `Apply update from ADB`), Recovery Mode option `Apply update from SD card`, or using an HTC RUU or `fastboot`.